# Scaling message queues with lots of API calls

Tags: performance, web-services, optimization

I have an application where some of my user's actions must be retrieved via a 3rd party api.

For example, let's say I have a user that can receive tons of phone calls. This phone call record should be update often because my user want's to see the call history, so I should do this "almost in real time". The way I managed to do this is to retrieve every 10 minutes the list of all my logged users and, for each user I enqueue a task that retrieves the call record list from the timestamp of the latest saved record to the current timestamp and saves all that to my database.

This doesn't seems to scale well because the more users I have, then, the more connected users I'll have and the more tasks i'll enqueue.

Is there any other approach to achieve this?

Comment: Does the 3rd party API provide any means to query calls other than by user id?

Comment: nope :-( just the user/account id

Comment: Maybe you can poll important userids more often. And userids where you know from the past that they have less updates less often.

Answer (score 0):

Seems straightforward with background queue of jobs. It is unlikely that all users use the system at the same rate so queue jobs based on their use. With fall back to daily.
You will likely at some point need more workers taking jobs from the queue and then multiple queues so if you had a thousand users the ones with a later queue slot are not waiting all the time.
It also depends how fast you need this updated and limit on api calls.
There will be some sort of limit. So suggest you start with committing to updated with 4h or 1h delay to always give some time and work on improving this to sustain level.
Make sure your users are seeing your data and cached api not live call api data incase it goes away.